# How to implement didSelectRow method in FBFriendPickerView

Tags: facebook, ios5, ios6, ios4

I am integrating latest Facebook SDKs in my app and its working great but now i want to do some advancements in it.I want that,when i click any of my friend from FBFriendPickerView i want to navigate to other view means i want to implement didSelectRow functionality as in tableview

Answer (score 0):

You can try the push view in "**friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange**" delegate method. 
I didn't try it, but should make the trick.
Just check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/protocol/FBFriendPickerDelegate/#friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange%3A

Comment: but where to implement it as its a delegate method , and we can't  edit delegate methods